# parse xml without namespaces

Tags: r, xml, xbrl, xml2

I'm trying to extract information from xml (or more precisely: xbrl) files, that reference a lot of namespaces. I don't really care about the namespaces, and I'd prefer to be able to search through the files without having to specify them.

Here is an example:

```
require(magrittr)
xml <-xml2::read_xml("http://regnskaber.virk.dk/21560853/ZG9rdW1lbnRsYWdlcjovLzAzLzdlLzk4L2JiLzg4L2NiNzctNDE2ZC1hOWJmLTkxN2QxZWRkMGY0Yg.xml")
```

this file contains the following node:

```
<cmn:IdentificationNumberOfAuditor contextRef=\"duration_IdentificationOfAuditorDimension_cmn_auditorIdentifier_only_1\">mne18078</cmn:IdentificationNumberOfAuditor>
```

I know I can find it using 
 xml2::xml_find_all(xml, '//cmn:IdentificationNumberOfAuditor')

But that is only if I know the namespace prefix, and I am not sure those are given the same way in all of the thousands of files I need to process. So I was hoping for this to work:

```
xml2::xml_find_all(xml2::xml_ns_strip(xml), '//IdentificationNumberOfAuditor')
```

because I thought xml_ns_strip would strip the xml file of the namespace information. However, xml_ns_strip does not actually seem to do anything at all, since:

```
identical(xml %>% as.character(), xml_ns_strip(xml) %>% as.character())
```

returns true.

Comment: I'm not sure about xml2, but xml_find_all second parameter looks like XPath and for that proper syntax to get all elements in any namespaces is `//*:IdentificationNumberOfAuditor`. so, what will be returned if you try `xml2::xml_find_all(xml2::xml_ns_strip(xml), '//*:IdentificationNumberOfAuditor')` ?

Comment: The second parameter is XPath, but //*:IdentificationNumberOfAuditor returns no nodes, however //*[local-name() = 'IdentificationNumberOfAuditor'] works. But that seems like an unwieldy way to build the XPath if I need to add more conditions etc later on

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the best solution i found to this problem is using an xslt stylesheet from https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/vi/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/r0054369.html

```
strip_namespaces <- function(x){
    stylesh <- '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

        <!-- keep comments -->
        <xsl:template match="comment()">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="*">
        <!-- remove element prefix -->
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <!-- process attributes -->
          <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <!-- remove attribute prefix -->
            <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
                      ')
  xslt::xml_xslt(x, stylesh)
}
```